# How can i download folder in oneDrive using microsoft graph API | python requests?

Tags: python-2.7, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, rest

I want to download folder and export as zip like we do in google drive. is there is anyway we can do in python requests. is there any endpoint for that?

```
downloadURL=x["@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"]
print " download Url : ",downloadURL
```

I am using this [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/drive/root:/testing](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buser-id%7D/drive/root:/testing) 1/new-file-name.docx.  for getting that URL. how can I achieve same for folder.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) Only **driveItems** with the file property can be downloaded. Folders don't have the property. I also don't get how a folder would need to be exported as pdf. I suggest you review your use case and find the files that you need to export to pdf instead of targeting folders.